# I can't get Ubuntu to connect to wireless

Tags: wireless

I am running 11.10 on a Dell Inspiron 9400. I ran lshw & it recognizes the BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN, but I don't see any wireless connections. This is a dual boot machine & the wireless works fine in Windows.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - but how did you install the b43 firmware? Ubuntu is completely new to me - so I definitely need stuff like that spelled out, if you'all don't mind! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the proprietary Broadcom-STA-Wireless-Driver. Go to the dash, search for "restricted drivers" and install it.

Comment: I have the Broadcom STA wireless driver installed already

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to open a terminal and install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

If "An unsupported BCM4311 Low-Power (LP-PHY) device was found." also install

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Then reboot

Instructions on how to install firmware for Broadcom chips.

http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43?highlight=%28bcm4311%29

Comment: Installing that firmware didn't change anything. I tried sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source then I entered sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer.  Still no luck

Comment: What worked was, I went to the system settings & removed the additional drivers for the broadcom, then I reinstalled the b43 firmware. After I rebooted the wireless showed up.